# Seagate Pipeline HD hard-drive not found in Asus UEFI bios

Tags: arch-linux, hard-disk, uefi, sata, asus

Seagate Pipeline HD hard-drive not found in Asus UEFI bios. Though when the machine is booted into Arch Linux with a live usb on the same machine it shows up.

Hard-Drive

- Model Name: Pipeline HD
- Model: ST3320310CS
- Firmware: ES11
- Brand: Seagate
- Size: 320GB

Mother Board

- Model Name: Asus B250 Expert Miner

Software

- Operating System: Arch Linux

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

As it turns out this model of hard-drive comes with (Power Up In Standby) or PUIS features enabled by default.

To fix this boot a live install of arch linux then find the disk in question using `fdisk -l`. Once you have found the corresponding path Ex: `/dev/sdX` use the command `hdparm -s 0 /dev/sdX` to disable PUIS. Then enter the command `sync` and finaly `shutdown`.

Then simply wait for the machine to stop completely before removing the usb and starting the computer.